# HTML and CSS Positionong text over image

Tags: html, css, layout

I kept the original question, because the problem persists.
Positioning text over image is a huge problem:

1) Float solution is not really suitable. Float actually breaks wordpress theme markup - which is really really bad. Unfortunately switching theme is not an option.

2) Background-image does not set image size right. Span does not have a fixed height, and is not supposed to have a fixed height.

3) Absolute position is a way, but it is a very bad way as far as i know.

4) Combining Absolute position, flex, float, relative position again gives no results as markup gets broken.

I am out of options, but i am still trying.

New updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/mdLvyn1g/24/

> Everyone don't judge me too hard, but I am stuck. I wrote a code which
>   can be found here:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/mdLvyn1g/
>
> That code is part of my Wordpress theme, which was made full-width.
>   The `.entry-header` inside css is actually needed, so don't mind it.
>   Images in the example are probably not working so i created:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/mdLvyn1g/3/
>
> The images here should work.
>
> Anyway my main problem is that i can't position text over image
>   properly.
>
> I've tried: absolute positioning, creating background-image for text,
>   grid layout, fiddling with css, everything else i could think of, but
>   all my attempts end either in what you see in fiddle or everything
>   breaks.
>
> Please also don't judge two separate tables too hard, but it was an
>   only thing i could think of, to make my layoyt look like:
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/mdLvyn1g/4/
>
> I am pretty sure that the whole html should be re-written, but have no
>   idea in which direction i should look for a start.
>
> !!!Important!!! The texts on the right or left should be kept. Images
>   shold fit cell. What i actually need is  a NEW text (color doesn't
>   matter) which would be above image.
>
> something like:
>
> http://www.pimpmaspace.com/Images/Holidays/graphics/img_text_13.gif
>
> BUT on my image and obviosly not Happy Easter text.
>
> !!!IMPORTANT!!!
>
> Positioning text above image itself is not a big problem. The big
>   problem is keeping everything else intact. Meaning the  somewhat
>   strange text/image order, and adding text above image.

Comment: The problem right now is a bit outdated. All answers below helped in part to find a somewhat working solution, which also was posted as an answer in order to keep questions and solutions separate

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/Daandeve/mdLvyn1g/15/

```
.wrapped-text-one {
color: white;
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 38%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: something along the lines, with black text kept. Absolute and relative positioning actually breaks everything

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you asking but if you asking to get the text from the table cells over the image and align it to the top then I managed to do that for you in the below fiddle where you can see the code:

```html
#headingOne {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Domz44/j3zausq6/

Comment: Also something along the lines, but image sizes are broken in your example

Answer (score 1):

okay other option is to remove the image tag a us a div tag instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/Daandeve/nogr891j/4/

than just use

```
background: url(https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/960/cpsprodpb/048E/production/_103566110_gettyimages-601066840.jpg) repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rework:

In the end the answer is still not quite what was desired in the first place and there are still some bugs in position. Also actual solution is highly dependable on the page layout, so it might not be adaptable at all.

The positioning of the text consist of two main parts:

HTML - a  single wrapper for both image and text:

```
<div class="test-wrapper">
  <img class="wrapped-img" src="https://cdn.allwallpaper.in/wallpapers/1920x1200/14340/animals-feline-forests-tigers-1920x1200-wallpaper.jpg" />
  <div class="img-title">It works</div>
</div>
```

A part of CSS describing the whole thing:

```
.test-wrapper {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.img-title {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  color: red;
  font-size: 56px;
}

.wrapped-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

It can be seeing that in the end the positioning of the text still came down to absolute positioning.

The actual resizing of this works pretty well considering everything.

The full problem was a bit broader than just positioning text over image.

Besides the image itself there was text either to the right or to the left of the image - basically a table. Par of the problem also included resizing the said text, and moving it when the screen became rather small.

The general outline of the full solution structure is:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-wrapper">
    <div class="column-wrapper column-left column-60-percent">
    ......
    </div>
    <div class="column-wrapper column-right column-40-percent">
    .....
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row-wrapper">
 ....
 </div>
</div>
```

The actual js code for resizing the whole thing is quite small but is highly dependant on the layout.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 373) {
    $('.column-wrapper.column-left.column-40-percent').remove().insertAfter($('.column-wrapper.column-right.column-60-percent'));
  } else {
    $('.column-wrapper.column-left.column-40-percent').remove().insertBefore($('.column-wrapper.column-right.column-60-percent'));
  }
})
```

Full example with all CSS can be still found at: http://jsfiddle.net/mdLvyn1g/29/

IMPORTANT SIDE NOTE:

As of right now I as still unsure about the whole thing. Solution seems to be working and even the text colors can be changed, however there are still bugs on resizing, because the text is positioned absolutely over the image.

JS part seems fine enough, but I might be wrong

Comment: Could some one please clarify if the js is ok or is it really really bad - like everything breaks bad?